# activerecord connection management and connection pools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, connection-pooling

I am connecting to a secondary DB with the following class, but think I am reaching the maximum connection pool as this class is called frequently, and I randomly fail to get results from queries.  Can someone help me with my syntax to ensure that I checkin and checkout a connection once a block or method has been run that uses the class?

```
class ReadDatabaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class=true
    self.table_name = "ATableName"
 end

def amethod
        ReadDatabaseConnection.establish_connection(@db_connection)
        records = ReadDatabaseConnection.where(condition)
end
```

Comment: Comment to say that I believe I have resolved this simply by changing the method to def amethod
        #ReadDatabaseConnection.establish_connection(@db_connection)
        records = ReadDatabaseConnection.where(condition)
ReadDatabaseConnection.connection_pool.disconnect!    end

Comment: You can answer your own question so if this is what fixed it I would put that as the answer and submit that